# Passing dynamic Columns to Pivot in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am new to oracle, I am trying to pass the dynamically generated column names to pivot in oracle using the below query

```
DECLARE
   v_cols VARCHAR2(100);
   v_query VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

    SELECT LISTAGG('''' ||product_code||'''',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_code) 
    INTO v_cols
    FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT product_code
        FROM pivot_test
        );

    v_query:='
      SELECT *
      FROM   (
              SELECT product_code,
                     quantity
              FROM   pivot_test) 
              PIVOT (sum(quantity) AS qunts 
              FOR product_code IN ('|| v_cols ||'));';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
    --dbms_output.Put_line(v_cols); 
    --dbms_output.Put_line(v_query);   
END;
```

The column generated is 'A','B','C','D' and the query generated with dynamic column is

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
              SELECT 
                     product_code,
                     quantity
              FROM   pivot_test) PIVOT (sum(quantity) AS qunts FOR product_code IN ('A','B','C','D'));
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

When I take the above query and run it separately it is running correctly but when I use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;` I get the error

```
  ORA-00911: invalid character
  ORA-06512: at line 20
```

I am not aware what is causing the problem here can any please point me what is wrong with this dynamic query execution

**Value used for testing**

```
CREATE TABLE pivot_test
  (
     id           NUMBER,
     customer_id  NUMBER,
     product_code VARCHAR2(5),
     quantity     NUMBER
  );

INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,1,'A',10);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2,1,'B',20);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3,1,'C',30);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (4,2,'A',40);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (5,2,'C',50);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (6,3,'A',60);
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (7,3,'B',70);
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (8,3,'C',80);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (9,3,'D',90);    
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (10,4,'A',100);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: You don't want to have the semi-colon at the end of the dynamically built statement.  If you remove that, does the problem go away?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes the problem is gone but, it shows the query is completed no result is shown don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the `ORA-00911` error you need to remove the `;` appended to the end of dynamically generated `v_query`
2. To display the output you can fetch the results into a cursor. The entire block can go into your dynamic SQL. A sample is below:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
   v_cols varchar2(100);
   v_query varchar2(4000);

begin

select listagg('''' ||product_code||'''',',') within group (order by product_code) into v_cols
from(
select  distinct product_code
 from pivot_test
);

v_query:='
declare
   cur_pivot_test   sys_refcursor;
   a    number;
   b    number;
   c    number;
   d    number;
begin
    open cur_pivot_test for
        select * from (select product_code, quantity from pivot_test) 
        pivot (sum (quantity)
        as qunts
        for product_code in ('|| v_cols ||'));

    fetch cur_pivot_Test into a, b, c, d;

    close cur_pivot_test;

    dbms_output.put_line (rpad(''A_QTY'',10) || '' | '' || rpad(''B_QTY'',10) || '' | '' || rpad(''C_QTY'',10) || '' | '' ||  rpad(''D_QTY'',10) );
    dbms_output.put_line (rpad(a,10) || '' | '' || rpad(b,10) || '' | '' || rpad(c,10) || '' | '' ||  rpad(d,10) );              

    end;
';

  execute immediate v_query;

end;
```

Output:

```
A_QTY      | B_QTY      | C_QTY      | D_QTY     
210        | 90         | 160        | 90
```